# Google Maps traffic vs Bing Maps traffic

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, traffic

I am looking into different maps providing traffic data, comparing the data and traffic information they provide (I'm located in Denmark (Odense) so not everyone has data for that region).

The two most obvious are Google Maps and Bing Maps, both who provide traffic information on their default map.The thing is, I need not only the map but numbers and the data behind the traffic. From my research, it seems that Google doesn't provide any service or API exposing this data, but Bing does.

Does anyone here know how accurate both maps are when displaying traffic information? How do they compare? How do they get there information? Has there been any research done that tries to determine which one provides better traffic information?

I know this is a broad question, but any answer pointing me to a research paper, article or anything will be appreciated.

And is there maybe an alternative that's even better then the two mentioned above, that provide traffic in Denmark?

Comment: Interested in this question, having troubles assessing these two options myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both platforms have reasonable traffic data in Denmark. Bing Maps does provide some API's traffic, primarily a tile layer with color coded roads based on the flow of traffic, and a REST service which provides incidents such as constructions, road closures or accidents.

If you want the raw flow numbers or car count type information, neither platform provides this.